# Apache virtual host basic authentication having no effect?

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, virtualhost, vps

I'm running a VPS with one domain on a virtual host through apache2. I'm trying to set up basic authentication on one of the domains. At the moment I have a .htpasswd file saved in `/etc/apache2/.htpasswd`. My virtual host is located at `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.co.uk.conf` and it looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.co.uk
    ServerAlias www.example.co.uk
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.co.uk/public_html

    <Directory /var/www/example.co.uk/public_html>
            AuthType Basic
            AuthBasicProvider file
            AuthName "Restricted Files"
            AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
            require valid-user
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.co.uk [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.co.uk
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is, the authentication doesn't seem to be having any effect. I'm quite new to this and as I understand it this is all I need to add, and it should prompt me for a password when I visit the site, but it has no effect.

Comment: You mean you can access that directory without being prompted a username/password box, right?

Comment: Yes, when I go to example.com it should give me a username/password box correct? But nothing happens it just goes straight to that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this at the end of your `Directory` section:

```
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
```